# WPF MVVM Binding Relative Source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm struggling with relative Sources. I'm inside Tab Items and I want to reach the parent ModelView. 
The goal is to make some context menu items invisble, if the item is the last tab.

ViewModel:

```
public bool IsLastTab => ItemCollection.Count > 1;
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWinodw"
    ...
    xmlns:ct="clr-namespace:ChromeTabs;assembly=ChromeTabs"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Main.ViewModel"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Main.Converters"
    xmlns:ctConv="clr-namespace:ChromeTabs.Converters;assembly=ChromeTabs"
    xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:Main.UserControls"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=Main}" ">
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    ...
</Window.Resources >
<Grid>
    <ct:ChromeTabControl x:Name="MyChromeTabControl"
                         TabPersistBehavior="Timed"
                         TabPersistDuration="0:0:0:5"
                         AddTabButtonBehavior="OpenNewTab"
                         Background="AliceBlue"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"
                          ...">
        ...
        <ct:ChromeTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ct:ChromeTabItem}}}">
                    ...
                    <Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Close"
                                      Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.CloseTabCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding IsLastTab,  
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ViewModelChromeTabs}}, 
                                                    Mode=OneWay, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                      CommandTarget="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            ...
                            <Separator />
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding IsPinned, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToPinTabTextConverter}}"
                                      Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.PinTabCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                      CommandTarget="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Grid.ContextMenu>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ct:ChromeTabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ct:ChromeTabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

It's working when I put it in the Item Class but there I have no Info about how many Tabs are left, and it seems counter logic to implement a messenger here for this.

Comment: Your ViewModel is probably not in the LogicalTree. You should bind to the datacontext of your window instead: `{Binding DataContext.IsLastTab,  
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}`

Comment: Hellor Freggar, didn't help. The Viewmodel works with
`ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"` but after the tag its only applying the items model

Comment: Then it's time to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because I have no clue other than that why the binding does not work. You could also look at the debug console for any Binding Expression errors.

Comment: Oh I'm stupid. `RelativeSource` won't work since a `ContextMenu` does not share the same VisualTree. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583507/wpf-binding-a-contextmenu-to-an-mvvm-command for more info

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly my question. Didn't find this one before. I'll try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `IsLastTab` like this:

```
public bool IsLastTab => ItemCollection.Count > 1;
```

This does not seem to determine whether the current tab is the last one.

You need something like that:

```
public bool IsLastTab => ReferenceEquals(this, ItemCollection.LastOrDefault());
```

(Since you did not post the underlying view models, this is just a guess. The exact code might change.)

And you also need to call [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.1) for the property "IsLastTab" for each tab item whenever the tab collection changes.

Comment: Well it doesn't reach the getter anyway yet. I could probably notify the last item in the list with the PropertyChanged Event. Thanks for this, i'll try it but it isn't my desired solution