# MRU Menu with Fluent.Ribbon - Can't wire Command to ModelView

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, icommand, fluent.ribbon

I'm new to WPF and am trying to build an MRU (most recently used items) menu with the [Fluent.Ribbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon) library.

Some digging in example code and the internet lead me to this point where I can generate the menuitems in splitbutton based on my list or recently used items. **But I can't figure out how to wire these items up to by OpenCommand**

```
class MainWindowVM : NotifyingObject
{
    private ICommand openCommand;
    private ObservableCollection<String> recentFileNames = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Bellerophon", "Athena" };
    public ICommand OpenCommand
    {
        get => openCommand;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<String> RecentFileNames
    {
        get => recentFileNames;
    }
}
```

The Viewmodel is applied to the RibbonWindow

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowVM />
</Window.DataContext>
```

And the current state of my Button is this:

```
<Fluent:SplitButton Header="Open..." Size="Middle"
        Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RecentFileNames}">
    <Fluent:SplitButton.Icon>
        <Image Source="Icons/folder-open-document.png" />
    </Fluent:SplitButton.Icon>
    <Fluent:SplitButton.LargeIcon>
        <Image Source="Icons/folder-open-document.png" />
    </Fluent:SplitButton.LargeIcon>
    <Fluent:SplitButton.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Fluent:SplitButton.ItemTemplate>
    <Fluent:SplitButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Fluent:MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Fluent:MenuItem}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
            <!--Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{}" /-->
        </Style>
    </Fluent:SplitButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</Fluent:SplitButton>
```

I've adapted this code from another SO question running on normal menuitems. But my command isn't getting called. I know that I'll eventually have to pass a parameter to distinguish between the different items but I can't even get it to run the plain command.

Comment: Do you see any data binding errors in the Visual Studio's Output window?

Comment: @dymanoid `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Fluent.MenuItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.OpenCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: You should add this information into your question. It's important enough to not be "just a comment". And it's of course a very nice hint to a solution.

Comment: And the solution is [already known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647539/2846483). It has nothing to do with the Fluent.Ribbon, it's a general problem with popups/context menus.