# `ContextMenu` Command binding inside `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a list view, where I wanted to Hide `ContextMenuItems` based on some value in the ListView Column. I could achieve this by moving ContextMenu to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`. Now my problem is that I am unable to fire Commands on MenuItem. This used to work when `ContextMenu` was set directly to `ListView`.

Here is what I have tried and failed. (Used `ElementType`, `ElementName`, Direct call etc.).

```
 <UserControl Name="RootElement" DataContext=.Some Context.....>     
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LicensesView}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Refresh 1" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LicenseListRefreshCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                                    <MenuItem Header="Refresg 2" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LicenseListRefreshCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Refresh 3" Command="{Binding Path= DataContext.LicenseListRefreshCommand, ElementName=RootElement}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Aktif,Converter= {StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Refresh 4" Command="{Binding LicenseListRefreshCommand}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>                           
                        </Setter>
                  </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}" Width="Auto"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Active" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Active}" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Company" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Company}" Width="60" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Demo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Demo}" Width="Auto" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because Style is a Disconnected property and hence it doesn' respect the visual tree.
I resolved this by using binding Proxy as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647539/3613702).

Key is to add DataContext reference as `StaticResource`.

```
<UserControl Name="RootElement" DataContext=.Some Context.....> 
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    <helper:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</UserControl.Resources>    
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LicensesView}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Refresh 1" Command="{Binding Path=Data.LicenseListRefreshCommand, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>                           
                    </Setter>
              </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Active" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Active}" Width="150" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Company" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Company}" Width="60" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Demo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Demo}" Width="Auto" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```